# Allowing table column to change color when clicking checkboxes

Tags: html, angularjs, checkbox, html-table

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2156/ (nCore)

I have a table and I am attempting to make it so that when one or more checkboxes in the table are clicked, the entire checkbox column changes color.

For better understanding, I want it to look like this before being clicked (which I already have now):

[image: Before]

And this is what I want it to look after one or more boxes are clicked:

[image: After]

Here is the HTML I have for the grid:

```
<table id="table-users" class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>
                User ID
                <a href="#" class="filter-link" ng-click="sortType = 'name'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'name' && sortReverse"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th>
                Notification Email
                <a href="#" class="filter-link" ng-click="sortType = 'email'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'email' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'email' && sortReverse"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th>
                Role
                <a href="#" class="filter-link" ng-click="sortType = 'type'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'type' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'type' && sortReverse"></span></a>
            </th>
            <th>
                Last Activity  
                <a href="#" class="filter-link" ng-click="sortType = 'lastActivity'; sortReverse = !sortReverse" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-alphabet"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lastActivity' && !sortReverse"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'lastActivity' && sortReverse"></span></a>             
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searching">
            <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
            <td>
              <!--<span class="circle-user" ng-class="{'circle-admin': user.type === 'Admin'}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>-->
              {{ user.type }}
            </td>
            <td>{{getLastDate(user.lastActivity) | date:'short'}}</td>
            <td><input id="multi-select" type="checkbox" ng-click="changeColumn()"></</td>
            <td>
              <span ng-hide="user.name === authInfo.user">
                <a href="#" ng-click="showUserAddDialog(user)">Edit</a>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span ng-hide="user.name === authInfo.user">    
                <a href="#" ng-click="showDeleteUser(user.id,user.name)">Delete</a>
              </span>
              </td>
            <td>
              <span ng-hide="user.name === authInfo.user">
                <a href="#" ng-click="showResetPassword(user.name)">Reset</a>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

JS:

```
$scope.changeColumn = function (){
     //Add code here that changes the CSS of that specific column so that it appears grey
}
```

Not sure where to go from here to make this change. Completely lost on what to include in the javascript function. Would I used ng-show and set it to true when selected?

Comment: you're going to have to show us what you tried before someone can help you resolving this...

Comment: can you create a plnkr or jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Will do on the jsfiddle, I'll need a few minutes to create it and simplify the code so it's more straightforward.

Comment: I'll add the javascript code that I attempted as well, webeno

Comment: jsfiddle with the code you've tried, you'll probably need to set some sort of flag to tell which one is being checked and then you can use ng-class to change the background based on the flag. Just thinking out loud here but I think it will fall somewhere in that line.

Comment: @nCore tried to condense it to something simpler and got this: https://jsfiddle.net/abeyvdzq/ the users list doesn't seem to show on jsfiddle -- not sure how to get it to function (fairly new at this, so apologies), but it functions when I run it locally.

Comment: I added a fiddle in your post, accept it and you forgot to select Angular in the javascript dropdown and because your fiddle doesn't have a controller.

Comment: Ah, that's what was missing, thanks. Approved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML:

```
<!-- Because this is in an ng-repeat (which creates it's own child scope), 
     you have to use $parent to get back to your original scope -->
<td ng-class="$parent.highlightCss">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="addChangeColumn()" ng-model="user.isChecked">
</td>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.addChangeColumn = function() {
  //check if any checkboxes have been checked
  var isAnyChecked = false;
  for (var i = 0, length = $scope.users.length; i < length; i++){
    if ($scope.users[i].isChecked){
      isAnyChecked = true;
      break;
    }
  }

  //if they have then set the $scope property to the style you want
  $scope.highlightCss = isAnyChecked ? 'highlight' : null;
};
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2162/)